# Rewrite the SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

This Dynamic SQL query hangs on prod every time. I have to rewrite this. Can someone please simplify this. Indexes are in place. The problem is query is very complex and records are in millions.

```
SET @SQL_NVAR=N'INSERT INTO #RECS_TEMP_TABLE (ROW_ID, STATUS)
    SELECT A.ROW_ID, ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DUP1_EXCPT_STAT) + '
    FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME_SRC + ' A (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #RECS_TEMP_TABLE R WHERE A.ROW_ID = R.ROW_ID )
    AND ENTY_ID=''' + @ENTY_ID + ''' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM (
        SELECT AA.ROW_ID FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME_SRC + ' AA(NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT HASH_CD, MAX(ROW_ID) ROW_ID FROM '+ @TABLE_NAME_SRC + '(NOLOCK) 
          GROUP BY HASH_CD HAVING COUNT(*)>1 
        ) BB ON AA.HASH_CD = BB.HASH_CD AND AA.ROW_ID = BB.ROW_ID 
        WHERE ENTY_ID=''' + @ENTY_ID + ''' 
      ) CC WHERE A.ROW_ID = CC.ROW_ID) 
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM (
          SELECT AA.ROW_ID FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME_SRC + ' AA(NOLOCK)  
          INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT HASH_CD, MAX(ROW_ID) ROW_ID FROM '+ @TABLE_NAME_SRC + '(NOLOCK) 
           GROUP BY HASH_CD HAVING COUNT(*)=1 
          ) BB ON AA.HASH_CD = BB.HASH_CD AND AA.ROW_ID = BB.ROW_ID 
          WHERE ENTY_ID=''' + @ENTY_ID + ''' 
        ) CC WHERE A.ROW_ID = CC.ROW_ID
      ) ORDER BY ROW_ID '
```

Comment: Indentations and new lines are your friend. This is painful to read as it stands now.

Comment: One thing is that second NOT EXISTS is almost identical to the first. If you make the first one have a "COUNT(*)=>1" instead of "COUNT(*)>1" you can eliminate that entire second NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Thanks for response. I haven't noticed that part as to maintain code modularity and requirement intact the previous developer kept them separate. I have modified it to count(1)>=1

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a simplified version that should run faster, but the fact is that slow queries can be caused by many things other than the query. You really need to provide full table definitions with indexes and an execution plan. Also, you should index the temp table if you are not already.

```
INSERT INTO #RECS_TEMP_TABLE (ROW_ID, STATUS)
    SELECT A.ROW_ID, ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @DUP1_EXCPT_STAT) + '
    FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME_SRC + ' A (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN #RECS_TEMP_TABLE R ON A.ROW_ID = R.ROW_ID
    LEFT JOIN ' + @TABLE_NAME_SRC + ' CC (NOLOCK) ON A.HASH_CD = CC.HASH_CD
        AND A.ROW_ID = CC.ROW_ID
        AND A.ENTY_ID = =''' + @ENTY_ID + '''
    WHERE ENTY_ID=''' + @ENTY_ID + ''' 
    AND R.ROW_ID IS NULL
    AND CC.HASH_CD IS NULL
```

Comment: I will give a try on this and let you know the results. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL has tools, that helps with query optimization.

- Use [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017) for catch one of executed queries.
- Use [Display the Estimated Execution Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017) for understanding, how
  server executing your query.
- Use [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/start-and-use-the-database-engine-tuning-advisor?view=sql-server-2017), which will help you find
  some other indexes, that server would use for execution of your
  query.

I am pretty sure, no one is able to optimise your query without more information (tables structure, created indexes, example of generated query, etc.).